# how can I parameterize on a 3 dimensional Cartesian plane a thick helix?

Tags: special-functions, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

there is a post already related to this subject

"Function on a 3 dimensional Cartesian plane that represents a helix?"

I was wondering though how to parameterize a helix with some thickness to it, like a torus but spiraling up and down like a helix

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
H(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, ct)
$$
That's your basic helix, with "slope" $c$. Its tangent vector is 
$$
v(t) = (-\sin t , \cos t, c)
$$
which happens to be a constant length. That means that *its* derivative is perpendicular to it, so we can write 
$$
n(t) = (-\cos t, -\sin t, 0)
$$
to get a vector perpendicular to $H(t)$. Geometrically, this just points from the helix towards its axis. Now by taking $v \times n$, we can get a vector perpendicular to both:
$$
w(t) = (c\sin t, -c\cos t, 1).
$$
(Small confession: I didn't do the cross product, so this might be some scalar multiple of the actual result.)

The length of $w$ is 
$$
\|w\|^2 = \sqrt{1 + c^2}
$$
so we let 
$$
u(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + c^2}} (c \sin t, -c \cos t, 1)
$$
which is a nice unit vector like $n(t)$.

Now we can define
$$
K(s, t) = H(t) + r\cos(s) n(t) + r\sin(s) u(t)
$$
and the graph of $K$ (as $s$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$, and $t$ ranges over whatever part of the real line you like) will be a tubular helix; it'll look best for a small value of $r$ like $\frac{1}{10}$, because $r$ is the radius of the "tube", and our base helix has a radius of $1$.

Comment: By the way, if you make $r$ vary with $t$ -- say $r = t/100$ for $t = 0 ... 50$, you'll get a nice "horn of plenty" kind of shape.